# dúvida inner join com prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Eu estava utilizando o select dessa maneira e funcionando perfeitamente

```
$id = (int)$_GET["id"];
$banco = $mysqli->query("SELECT os.os_solicitado,os.os_status,cliente.cliente_emailfinanceiro FROM os left join cliente on os.os_razaosocial = cliente.cliente_razaosocial where os.os_id = $id"); 
while($dados = $banco->fetch_array()) { 
$status = $dados["os_status"];
$solicitado = $dados["os_solicitado"];
$emailfin = $dados["cliente_emailfinanceiro"];
```

Porém para melhorar a segurança estou alterando para dessa maneira

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT os.os_solicitado,os.os_status,cliente.cliente_emailfinanceiro FROM os left join cliente ON os.os_razaosocial=cliente.cliente_razaosocial WHERE os.os_id = ? ");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['id']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
while($dados = $stmt->fetch_array()) { 
$status = $dados["os_status"];
$solicitado = $dados["os_solicitado"];
$emailfin = $dados["cliente_emailfinanceiro"];
```

porém dessa segunda maneira dá erro, não conecta no banco e não consigo identificar o que é

Comment: Posta o erro que esta aparecendo

Comment: No meu caso aparece Error connecting to database

Comment: Então posta o código da conexão onde você passa os dados do banco de dados, lembre-se de alterar os dados reais para dados fictícios.

Comment: mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
set_exception_handler(function($e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand
});
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
$mysqli->set_charset("ISO-8859-1");

Comment: lembrando que fazer sem o prepare, funciona certinho

Comment: Para facilitar a leitura, procura colocar as informações adicionais na própria pergunta, editando ela.

Comment: substitua o conteúdo do exit por `$e->getMessage()`, para ver qual erro realmente esta acontecendo.

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92824/discussion-between-leonardo-barros-and-murilo-albeest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione depois do `$stmt->execute();`

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

e no `while($dados = $stmt->fetch_array()) {`

altere para

```
while($dados = $result->fetch_array()) {
```